# yeast protein secondary structure

Tags: bioinformatics, proteins, yeast, protein-structure, structure-prediction

i have a fasta file of yeast orfs (from the [SGD](http://www.yeastgenome.org/) database) and i need to find out(predicted) secondary structure/classification for all of them (so ~6K queries and doing this by hand on numerous available websites is not an option). is [CATH](http://www.cathdb.info/) database a place that can give me this info? (so far i struggle to recover anything that can help me from the website but perhaps i am missing something), if not what's the best way/software to go about it? surely, these predictions have been done before and there is a databse somewhere -- yeast is too much of an important organism, with a lot of information about its genome.

Comment: Lot of resources are available [online](http://expasy.org/resources/search/keywords:secondary%20structure%20prediction), choose depending on your requirement and protein of interest.

Comment: @Dexter, thank you. i am well aware of this site and others but i need the procedure automated: i have ~6k ORFs and i need to run all of them through the algorithm to obtain secondary structure.

Comment: Then you need little bit programming with [server queries](http://ecoliwiki.net/colipedia/index.php/ExPASy_proteomics_server). Alternately, search for server which accept batch sequences.

Comment: @Dexter unfortunately this is not something i am able to do, so i was more after either a piece of code (R/python) or a relatively easy to use software. i am struggling with installing and running s2D (whose server version i've tried and approved) at the moment and it's a nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments I understood that you need to predictions in bulk. You can use API based system of [JPred](http://www.compbio.dundee.ac.uk/jpred/). They allow you to submit more than 1000 jobs per user per day. You can go through instructions step by step from their [documentation](http://www.compbio.dundee.ac.uk/jpred4/downloads/Jpred_4_Tutorial_on_Scheduled_Mass_Submission.pdf). It looks simple !

Another hit I got while searching is [Phyre2](http://www.sbg.bio.ic.ac.uk/phyre2/html/page.cgi?id=index_advanced). I am sure there are many such servers.

Comment: Phyre2 took a non-trivial amount of time for me to get a model back. I don't know if their batch processing is any quicker, though.

Comment: @canadianer I haven't checked any of these sites. API integration sounds interesting. My personal choice will be submit to ExPASY server through python queries but OP is not (or don't want to be) a programmer I guess.

Comment: @Dexter like you said JPred was very easy to set up and use, thank you again. and i am programming myself, however i am not very experienced in python and i don't have much time to learn how to submit queries etc in python at the moment

Comment: No problem. Go with whatever you find easier. At the end only thing matter is to get your job done.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to Dexter's answer i found that the [s2D](http://www-mvsoftware.ch.cam.ac.uk/index.php/s2D) does exactly what i need. setting up might be a bit tricky and is certainly more involved than setting JPred up but using it is easy and the output is in a nicer format.